# msys-1.0's dd on windows

Tags: windows, dd, mingw, msys

msys-1.0 (MinGW) has an implementation of `dd` usable on windows (`dd.exe`) but windows does not have file representations of drives to use with dd. Or does it? Afaik dd operates on files.

Is there a way (device names or similar) to use msys-1.0's `dd.exe` to copy e.g., an attached D drive to a file?